# Intrinsic gain of NMOS

Tags: amplifier, analog, nmos

In Razabi's Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuits textbook, the example 3.2 asks for the small signal voltage gain of the circuit below:

[image]

He explains that since the current source I1 introduces an infinite impedance, the gain is limited by the output resistance of M1, and therefore the voltage gain is given by $$ A_v = -g_m r_O$$
I don't understand how you can just replace the current source I1 with an open circuit to calculate the voltage gain. I understand that the ideal current source has an infinite resistance in parallel, but that doesn't mean you can replace the current source with an open circuit (since it is in parallel). What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A small-signal analysis deals with the *change* in the response of a linear circuit as a consequence of a small-signal excitation *superimposed* in addition to the circuit's DC condition.

A small-signal model of an ideal current source is simply an open circuit (i.e. infinite impedance) - no *additional* current flows through that branch regardless of what you do. Hence, there is no additional conductance, parallel impedance, or source needed to represent the small-signal model of that current source.

On the other hand, a non-ideal current source with a parallel output impedance \$r_{o,src}\$ has a small signal model that is just a resistor - precisely with value \$r_{o,src}\$.

In practice, when you do design this circuit on an integrated circuit, you'll use a [current mirror](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_mirror#Basic_MOSFET_current_mirror) to implement your current source. In the small-signal model that MOSFET has a constant Vgs so its transconductance won't appear, and your non-ideal current source's small-signal model will just be the \$r_o\$ of the mirror.

Comment: Ah that makes sense! I didn't think about the small-signal model dealing with only the incremental change. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Think of Ro as a resistor in parallel with the FET's source-drain (it's not quite that).

In the circuit above, the DC value of VIN would be chosen to allow the FET to be biased correctly -- the drain would sink a current of exactly I1 and the drain V would be at about VDD/2.

Now, for small perturbations in VIN, the drain current -- ID of the *intrinsic* FET would change. This current will change the current in Ro, and so the drain voltage will change (by delta_ID * Ro). Note that the total current into the drain pin of the FET remains constant (== I1), but as VIN changes, the 'extra' current generated gets absorbed by Ro, and consequently changes the drain voltage.